# Script to Remove files from Xcodeproj

Tags: xcode, xcodeproj

I need to remove the reference to some files from my Xcode project from command line. I'm trying with the ruby lib Xcodeproj, but I can't understand how to do it:

```
proj = Xcodeproj::Project.open(project_file)
proj.targets.each do |target|
    path = "../Pods/MyFolder/Externals/**/*"
    dir = Dir.glob(path).select{ |e| File.file? e }
    dir.each do |file|
        proj.files.delete(file)
    end
end

proj.save
```

After running the script nothing is changed inside my project.

Comment: Use `file.remove_from_project` instead of `proj.files.delete(file)`

Comment: Where to write this script?

Comment: @Jenish Create a text file with extension .rb, you can run it with: ruby filename.rb from your terminal. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Hello_world

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I tried 'reject', 'filter' ... Nothing worked.

The solution that worked was to replace:

```
proj.files.delete(file)
```

for

```
file.remove_from_project
```